# How to run a method, if the event has finished?

Tags: angular

I try to create a small webapp to upload images.

```
    <input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="image" (change)="imageToList()" accept="image/*"  capture>
```

In Angular I run the following code to add the image to a Array and perform the upload if the user has finished with his proced.  No I just want to show the values in the input.files.

```
   constructor() {
        this.input = document.getElementById('imageUpload') ;
    }

    imageToList() {
        console.info(this.input.files[0]);
    }
```

I recieve the error, `Cannot read property 'files' of null`. If I run the commandline in google crome, I see that `files` exists with the choosen file.

[image]

It looks like a timeing problem, but I have no idea to fix it. Is there a way in Angular2 to run a method after a listener? Or is there an other usercase for thinks like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way - using Lifecycle hooks (probably `ngAfterContentInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`):
[documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

Right way to do it - using `@ViewChild`:
[documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)

*Update*: sorry, probably you don't need to have reference to your input inside of `@Component` at all. Try

```
(change)="imageToList($event)"
imageToList(event: any): void{
    console.log(event);
}
```